# Printing to multiple printers from .NET WebBrowser - program hangs unless a MessageBox is used

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, printing, webbrowser-control

The [`WebBrowser.Print`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print?view=net-5.0) method has the limitation of not allowing the caller to specify a printer other than the system's default one. As a workaround, it has been suggested<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/714543/3258851), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49243011/3258851)</sup> to alter the system's default printer prior to calling `Print()`, however it's also reported<sup>[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3675430/3258851)</sup> (and I experienced firsthand) that the `WebBrowser` instance will continue to print to the previously defined printer even after the system default is altered.

To work around that, registering a handler to the [`PrintTemplateTeardown` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768296(v=vs.85)) by accessing the underlying ActiveX object of the managed WebBrowser instance and waiting for the event to fire before printing further documents has been proposed<sup>[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675430/programmatically-changing-the-destination-printer-for-a-winforms-webbrowser-cont?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment3925301_3675430), [[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11028499/3258851)</sup>, and that is what I am trying to implement. I simplified what is a much more complex program to the MVCE presented below.

*(The program is a .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms application, with one form containing nothing more than a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-5.0) object named `bw`.)*

***Form1.cs***

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Management;

namespace Demo_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                BwPolling();

                Thread.Sleep(20000);
            }
        }

        private void BwPolling()
        {
            string[] htmlStrings = { "test1", "test2" };

            foreach (string html in htmlStrings)
            {
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    PrinterSettings.StringCollection installedPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;
                    foreach (string printer in installedPrinters)
                    {
                        string[] validPrinterNames =
                        {
                            "Microsoft Print to PDF",
                            "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
                        };

                        if ( validPrinterNames.Contains(printer) )
                        {
                            SetDefaultPrinter(printer);
                            
                            var wb = new WebBrowser();
                            wb.DocumentText = html;

                            // With inspiration from code by Andrew Nosenko <https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio>
                            // From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737374/3258851
                            // CC BY-SA 3.0

                            var wbax = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)wb.ActiveXInstance;

                            TaskCompletionSource<bool> printedTcs = null;
                            SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler printTemplateTeardownHandler =
                            (p)
                                => printedTcs.TrySetResult(true); // turn event into awaitable task

                            printedTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                            wbax.PrintTemplateTeardown += printTemplateTeardownHandler;

                            try
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Printing to " + printer);

                                wb.Print();

                                printedTcs.Task.Wait();
                            }

                            finally
                            {
                                wbax.PrintTemplateTeardown -= printTemplateTeardownHandler;
                            }

                            wb.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private static bool SetDefaultPrinter(string name)
        {
            // With credits to Austin Salonen <https://stackoverflow.com/users/4068/austin-salonen>
            // From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/714543/3258851
            // CC BY-SA 3.0
            using ( ManagementObjectSearcher objectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer") )
            {
                using ( ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = objectSearcher.Get() )
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject mo in objectCollection)
                    {
                        if ( string.Compare(mo["Name"].ToString(), name, true) == 0 )
                        {
                            mo.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter", null);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem being faced** is when I remove the message box from the `BwPolling()` method, right before calling `Print()`, i.e. when this line is removed:

```
MessageBox.Show("Printing to " + printer);
```

then the program freezes, nothing is printed, and the process must eventually be terminated.

I believe I can sort of understand the issue on its surface: `WebBrowser` requires an STA thread with an active message loop<sup>[[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325022/3258851), [[7]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/3258851)</sup>; by calling `printedTcs.Task.Wait();` within a `Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate` block *(called on the `Form1` instance; `this.` is ommited)*, I am blocking the STA thread and the application hangs waiting for an event that is never fired. This is in fact [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734151/print-webbrowser-without-previewing-i-e-single-click-print/19737374#comment29559037_19737374) under the answer I credited in my code.

Just can't figure out what a proper solution would be. Got lost in attempts to run the printing routine in a secondary thread. Maybe something wrong in my execution, guess I require assistance in this. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Try a small delay, experiment with the optimal duration instead of the message box

Comment: I see your still working on this problem. I would seriously consider using an alternative to `WebBrowser`

Comment: @Simon, I tried, to no avail; delaying execution by `Thread.Sleep()` has the same hanging effect.

Comment: @TheGeneral I did! Very seriously - `WebBrowser` has been nothing short of a pain in the arse. But all things considered, found no suitable solution. Even came so far as to do what's suggested at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#printing. Created more problems than it solved in my scenario.

Comment: What if you work around it by a message box close command after displaying it?

Comment: Install-Package AutoClosingMessageBox

Comment: Have you tried `Application.DoEvents()` and `Thread.Yield()`?

Comment: @Simon that would be an acceptable hack for my immediate problem... Something to try tomorrow, will report back.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I have not. How do you suggest I do so?

Comment: As a replacement of the `MessageBox.Show(...` line. I don't expect it to solve the hanging problem, but you could give it a try.

Comment: What you are probably searching for is a way to get the effect of `MessageBox.Show`, without actually showing anything to the user. A kind of invisible transient message box.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, `Application.DoEvents()` seems to have worked in my local tests with fake printers. I'll have to wait until tomorrow to test on my client's machine; if it proves to be robust enough I guess I can settle with that solution. Thanks

Comment: @TheodorZoulias As an update, the proposed workaround has been working well for the past couple of days in the live application.

Comment: Happy to hear that! But I guess it's too trivial a solution (and probably too accidental) to post it as an answer.