# How to send formatted HTML from a database to a specific (non-default) printer with no user interaction in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm currently pulling HTML data from a database and displaying it in a WebBrowser control in my VB.Net application so that it's correctly rendered. The next step is to print it, but I need to be able to send it to a specific printer rather than the default printer. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You might check this thread

[Printing From WebBrowser control prints to wrong printer after setting default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561078/printing-from-webbrowser-control-prints-to-wrong-printer-after-setting-default)

Basically, remember the current default printer, set the desired printer as default, print, then restore the original default printer.