# win7 default printer is not selected printer

Tags: .net, printing

I have to print some html documents from my program. Because of that I cannot use .NET's provided interfaces (like `PrintDocument`) but I do kind of workaround.
For that I do separate form with `WebBrowser` control for showing a document before printing with few basic controls for determining printing parameters such is choosing printer for print that document.

Parts of code:
Filling printers to combobox:

```vb
For Each pkInstalledPrinter As String In System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
     cboInstalledprinters.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinter)
Next pkInstalledPrinter

''p_printer is determined by program but should be changable
''if p_printer is empty then it should be system''s default printer

If p_printer = "" Then
    p_printer = getDefaultPrinter()
End If
cboInstalledprinters.SelectedItem = p_printer
```

For changing a desired printer user can use combobox `cboInstalledprinters` like this:

```vb
Private Sub cboInstalledprinters_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboInstalledprinters.SelectedIndexChanged
    p_printer = cboInstalledprinters.SelectedItem.ToString
    SetDefaultPrinter(p_printer)
End Sub
```

Printing of webBrowser content is like this:

```vb
 Dim MyWeb As Object = WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
 Try
     MyWeb.ExecWB(olecmdid.OLECMDID_PRINT, PromptUser, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
 Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
 End Try
 MyWeb = Nothing
```

`PromptUser` is of `execopt` type and can be determined from outside a function when calling for a print.

Used functions:
`getDefaultPrinter`

```vb
Public Function getDefaultPrinter() As String
Dim oldPrinter As String
    Dim oPS As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
    Try
        oldPrinter = oPS.PrinterName
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        oldPrinter = ""
    End Try
    Return oldPrinter
End Function
```

`setDefaultPrinter`

```vb
<DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint:="SetDefaultPrinter", _
 SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
 Public Function setDefaultPrinter(ByVal strPrinterName As String) As Boolean
End Function
```

All of that works good.
But what is a problem?

When I switch (chose) different printers from combobox I can see how default printer changes in ControlPanel/Devices and Printers what mean that default printers are switched well (green checkmark moves according to chose from combobox).

I thought that program will automatically use default printer for that printings, but when I press a print button to invoke printing my program don't print to default printer. Instead of that SELECTED one is used. When I call print function with `execopt.OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER` I get additional dialog with printers where I can see which printer is default but that printer is NOT SELECTED.

Actually, with my changes on combobox default printer changes but SELECTED PRINTER doesn't change at all (remains remembered from first usage) and program wants to print through selected printer, not default printer. That behavior may be good but problem is that I can't set that selection with a program. I can change default printer with code but selected printer only by exiting a program and coming back.

How to select a printer with combobox `cboInstalledprinters` so program will use selected one automatically?

Comment: This is a FAQ, google "webbrowser set default printer".

Comment: Hello Hansy, According to readen I added HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup\printer = p_printer and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\AlwaysUseDefaultPrinter = yes but program behaves same as before. Some further ideas or advices to try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing From WebBrowser control prints to wrong printer after setting default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561078/printing-from-webbrowser-control-prints-to-wrong-printer-after-setting-default)