# Error when printing file but not when printing web page

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, printing

Using the [InternetExplorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object, I'm able to print a web page.  But when I try to print a file, I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   The object invoked has disconnected
>   from its clients.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419412/print-html-document-from-windows-service-without-print-dialog/1712981#1712981)):

```
public class Program
{
    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        // this works
        (new HTMLPrinter()).Print("www.google.com");

        // this brings up the file in a browser 
        // but then throws an exception when checking print status!
        (new HTMLPrinter()).Print("C:\Temp\test.html");  
    }
}

public class HTMLPrinter
{
    private bool documentLoaded;
    private bool documentPrinted;

    private void ie_DocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {
        documentLoaded = true;
    }

    private void ie_PrintTemplateTeardown(object pDisp)
    {
        documentPrinted = true;
    }

    public void Print(string htmlFilename)
    {
        documentLoaded = false;
        documentPrinted = false;

        InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorerClass();
        ie.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(ie_DocumentComplete);
        ie.PrintTemplateTeardown += new DWebBrowserEvents2_PrintTemplateTeardownEventHandler(ie_PrintTemplateTeardown);

        object missing = Missing.Value;

        ie.Navigate(htmlFilename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        // An exception is thrown at 
        // SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass.QueryStatusWB
        // only when trying to print a file!
        // Exception details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
        // The object invoked has disconnected from its client.
        while (!documentLoaded && ie.QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT) != OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED)
            Thread.Sleep(100);        

        ie.ExecWB(OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, ref missing, ref missing);
        while (!documentPrinted)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        ie.DocumentComplete -= ie_DocumentComplete;
        ie.PrintTemplateTeardown -= ie_PrintTemplateTeardown;
        ie.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I saved the google web page to disk, and that one printed.  Seems like it has something to do with my html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the program as Administrator.