# Print PDF file with the default printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, httpbackend

I'm developing a backend application using C# and I need to do a very simple thing: to print an existing PDF file using the default printer when the application receives some HTTP request. I don't need any "printer choose" window or anything else, because the application runs on server and only responds to HTTP requests. I just need to silently print a PDF file when my backend receives a request to some URL. I've been looking on the internet for a couple of hours, found classes like `PrintDocument` and `PdfDocument`, but I couldn't understand how to use them.

Comment: I think it's best to try and ask questions pertaining to how to use PrintDocument instead.  When you say couldn't figure it out you may want to post questions regarding that.  I think that is a pretty standard way of printing in c#

Comment: I guess `PrintDocument` is for Windows Forms only, but I'm using a different framework `NancyFX`.

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419412/print-html-document-from-windows-service-without-print-dialog

Comment: Hey, You can try this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857500/c-sharp-how-to-programmatically-print-an-existing-pdf-file-using-printdocument